# Create Device specific context robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

I am new to Robolectric and I am trying to use it to unit test my application.
A lot of my functions have Device specific contexts like,

isNetworkAvailable(Context c), isLocationAvailable(Context c) etc.

I am not sure, how to test functions like these using Robolectric.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,